# In logstash config file, How to calculate the difference between two UNIX format date fields?

Tags: logstash

This is the filter part in my logstash config file.

```
filter {
mutate {  
    split => ["message", "|"]
    add_field => {
        "start_time" => "%{[message][1]}"
        "end_time" => "%{[message][2]}"
        "channel" => "%{[message][5]}"
        "[range_time][gte]" => "%{[message][1]}"
        "[range_time][lte]" => "%{[message][2]}"
        # "duration" => "%{[end_time]-[start_time]}"
    }
    # remove_field => ["message"]
} 
date {
    match => ["start_time", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
    target => "start_time"
}
date {
    match => ["end_time", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
    target => "end_time"
}
ruby { 
    code => 
    "
    event.set('start_time', event.get('start_time').to_i)
    event.set('end_time', event.get('end_time').to_i)
    " 
}
mutate {
    remove_field => ["message", "@timestamp"]
}
ruby { 
    init => "require 'time'" 
    code => "event['duration'] = event['end_time'] - event['start_time'];" 
}
```

In the end, I wanna create a new field named duration to represent the difference between end_time and start_time.

Obviously, the last ruby part was wrong. How could I write for this part?

Comment: If your time is in UNIX Time then your `date` filters are not working as well, UNIX time does not have the format `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. To parse a UNIX time with the date filter you should use `UNIX` or `UNIX_MS`, depending on the precision. Can you share an example of your message?

Comment: @leandrojmp    Sure. One of my message was like |20210401000852|20210401000858|2||SCTV-2||||||0||||.  And I found some information said, if wanna change my date field to UNIX format, I have to change it to UTC format first. That's why I changed my date format to UTC first, then changed it to Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you must make sure that the field you want to put the duration in exists prior to your setting of the value.
Make sure you add the field up front.
As it will be numeric you could do it like this

```
mutate {
  add_field {
    "duration" => 0
  }
}
```

After this you can calculate the value and set it using ruby

```
ruby {
  code => "event.set('duration', event.get('end_time').to_i - event.get('start_time').to_i)"
}
```